# Oracle: converting Date value to realted amount of minutes from the beginning of the day

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I need to convert value of Date type to related amount of minutes to store it in Number type column. E.g. given "01-01-2015 04:00:00AM", result - 240. Is there any Oracle functions to do that? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

If you are simply trying to determine the number of minutes from midnight

```
your_date - trunc(your_date)
```

returns a number of days.  Multiply by 24 to get hours and by 60 to get minutes

```
(your_date - trunc(your_date)) * 24*60
```

If you are trying to do something else, you'll have to edit your question to better explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to know how many total minutes have passed from the beginning of a day having only time in standard format (with hours and minutes).

Comment: For instance, 16 hours and 45minutes is just basically 1006 minutes. (16*60 + 45).

Comment: So, i need to get hours, multiply it by 60 and add minutes.

Comment: @psed - Then it sounds like what I posted is what you want.  If the time is 4:45 pm, the expression I posted returns 1005 (I assume 1006 is a typo).

Answer (score 1):

There also built-in format function to get seconds since midnight although I don't like string conversion behind it:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'SSSSS')) / 60 FROM DUAL
```